# iAd and AdMob ads are not showing in released iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, ios, admob, iad

I developed my app with two kinds of banners: iAd and AdMob.
When iAd banner fails to load then AdMob banner loaded.
When I tested my app it showed black iAd test banner correctly but in released version of app there is no banners at all.
 I've tested it with web debugging proxy: requests are sending only to iAd server but never to AdMob. Seems like iAd banners are loaded successfully but never shown. In itunesconnect the iAd status is Live Adds.
Thanks.

Comment: For the iAds, it may be that the requests are not being filled. Not every request to the iAd server returns an actual ad. Fill rates have ranged from 20-60% in my personal experience.

Comment: @Greg, but how to explain that there are no any requests to the admob server?    Admob banners should have been loaded when iAd request is not filled.

Comment: I don't know. I've never used Admob; I was just taking a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is solved. If someone will face this problem in the future: in my situation the solution was in patient waiting. Since two weeks after AppStore upload banners suddenly appeared. I think Apple needs some time to generate banners content according to the application audience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the BannerViewController in the iAd sample code and find that iAd works perfectly when built for iOS5 but does not show up when built for iOS6, then find the line in BannerViewController: bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size]; and remove the underscore. I implemented iAD in my ShareMonitor app and, although I had identical code to the sample code, ads would only appear when built for iOS5. After some debugging and trial and error, I found this resolved the issue and ads in my app worked perfectly.